# Eclipse doesn't apply changes in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

So, this question isn't about my coding knowledge and technical competence, that's why I'll omit the code.

The problem is that since an unknown moment in the past, nothing I declare in the Manifest has any impact on my Android application. These are only a handful of examples and expected outcomes that fail to perform:

- Declaring service in the Manifest doesn't allow it to be run via `startWakefulService(Context, Intent)` method
- Changing the class name of an already declared (it doesn't work either) receiver doesn't cause the application to crash on launch (if Manifest would work it should crash due to ResourceNotFound)
- There is a declaration of a receiver that isn't present in the project (my coworker didn't commit it to the repository) and it also doesn't crash the application.

I've tried so many things that I don't want to list them, I'll keep browsing through your answers and hopefully find something I haven't tried.

The code itself works. I've copy/pasted it in another project and everything works okay. Also in the original application everything works except for the parts that are handled by the Manifest.

EDIT: Forgot to add, although it is implied - this is a collab project on a repository. All the conflicts have been resolved.

Comment: If clean & rebuild doesn't help, also make sure yoy don't have more than copy of the manifest and modifying the wrong one.

Comment: Agreed. This feels like you are editing the wrong file. Bear in mind that Eclipse itself does not do much with your manifest AFAIK -- that is used by tools like **`aapt`**, which are also building your other (working) project(s).

Comment: I checked both the Manifest in the root folder and the one in the `bin/` folder and they are the same as the one in the Eclipse.

Comment: Did you save the manifest file? By save i mean pressing ctrl/cmnd + c. If so, then check if the changes persist by navigating to the manifest file outside eclipse.